# MySQL Procedure ignoring LEAVE statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here's the procedure:

```
main:BEGIN

# make sure a game isnt already running
SELECT COUNT(*), `winner` INTO @running, @winner
    FROM `games`
    WHERE `winner` IS NULL;

IF @running != 0 THEN
    SELECT 0 as 'success', @running as 'running', @winner as 'winner';
    LEAVE main;
END IF;

SELECT `id` INTO @lastGame 
    FROM `games` 
    WHERE 1
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 1;

SELECT `charity_id` INTO @lastWinner
    FROM `runners` 
    WHERE `game_id` = @lastGame
    ORDER BY `donated` DESC
    LIMIT 1;


INSERT INTO `games` (`target`)
    VALUES (_target);

SET @gameId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO `runners` (`game_id`, `charity_id`)
    VALUES (@gameId, @lastWinner);

SET @runners = 1;

WHILE @runners < 5 DO
    SELECT `id` INTO @rand FROM `charities` 
        WHERE `id` != @lastWinner 
        ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO `runners` (`game_id`, `charity_id`)
        VALUES (@gameId, @rand);

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @runners 
        FROM `runners`
        WHERE `game_id` = @gameId;
END WHILE;

SELECT 1 as 'success', @gameId as 'gameId';

END
```

When I run this example where there exists in the `games` table a single entry with `winner` = 3, the returned result is:

```
success: 0, running: 1, winner: NULL
```

but all the code after the `IF @running != 0 THEN ... END IF;` block is executed as well!  A new game is inserted into `games` and five new `runners` are added to the table.

1) if `winner` = 1 then why is @running == 1?

2) if that IF ... END IF; block is being run, why isn't it LEAVE-ing the main block, and instead continuing on to execute the rest of the code?

Comment: Missing some parts of your code here: Where is the end main?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen  The final `END` is the end of the `main:BEGIN` block.  (The closing `main` is unnecessary in MySQL.)

Answer (score 0):

Created a small test: the LEAVE not working is not re-producable (so technically mysql does what it should do).

This code is however interesting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `winner` INTO @running, @winner
FROM `games`
WHERE `winner` IS NULL;
```

This will return **@running=0**, and **@winner=NULL**. With **@running=0** it is logical the rest of your code just runs.
Where the @running=1 (and your whole logging line) comes from is vague. Best chance is: Make certain this is the code you are using and not some other (older?) version by dropping the procedure and re-creating it.

Comment: I've dropped, recreated, edited, and tested many times trying to figure this out.  This morning I gave up and just made it a big IF ... ELSE block.  :-/  I agree: when @running = 1, the rest of the code *should not run*... but it most certainly does.

Comment: Is the your games table really just one record? I find it hard to believe this goes wrong on mysql level (I know of a series of bugs in mysql, but this one is just too simple).

Comment: At the time of the test, yeah, the games table had only one record.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: No, however you are describing something odd, and 99.99% of questions regarding code on StackOverflow is user error: I am looking for user error (nothing personal: Sometimes spend days on my own user errors).